# ufw not logging on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, 22.04, firewall, log, ufw

I have no ufw logs on my minimized Ubuntu 22.04 server.

sudo ufw status verbose output:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
```

On the internet I found I need rsyslogd enabled. On Ubuntu 22.04 minimzed rsyslog is not installed by default and I want to keep it like that.

How can make ufw to log correctly without installing rsyslog?

Comment: Seems you found an answer but have not said why you do not want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but with `rsyslog` installed, i.e., no `ufw.log` was being written. It turned out that the ownership and permissions set for `ufw.log` were wrong.

This is how I solved the problem:

```
sudo touch /var/log/ufw.log
sudo chown syslog:adm /var/log/ufw.log
sudo chmod 640 /var/log/ufw.log
```

I believe `ufw.log` is an excerpt from `syslog`, so `rsyslog` is required.